# TinyMCE editor is stripping my html code in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, tinymce, joomla2.5

I have a problem in my TinyMCE editor in joomla. Every time i make any changes from the editor my html code gets messed up.

I tried using a different editor like (JCE Editor), but the result is the same.

I am new to joomla so if anyone suggest me how to go about in fixing this problem

Thanks

Comment: Make use of `htmlentities` ?

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran: what i would like to do is i want the user to add/edit the content using the editor since the user of the website is not aware of any html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got a solution for this.

Instead of using TinyMCE editor i switched to JCE Editor and followed these steps

Change the defualt setting of JCE Editor

[image: JCE EDitor]

Once inside the JCE Administration area, click on Default editor profile

[image: JCE Defualt]

Inside the Default editor profile, click on the Editor Parameters tab, and then click on the Advanced tab. Depending on which type of code you d like to save in your articles, you can choose to allow JavaScript, PHP, CSS, and XHTML. Please note that these are disallowed by default because they can be potentially dangerous to your site. It s always best to create a backup of your site before adding code like this. Don t forget to save your work after you make these changes.

[image: JCE Params]

Next, go to the Plugin Parameters tab, and then click on the Media Support tab. As illustrated in the screenshot below, you may also choose to display some additional elements. You can click on "Save & Close" in the toolbar when you re done. That s all the configuration that you should have to do through the JCE Editor.

[image: profile]

You can test your changes by embedding a YouTube video into an article or Custom HTML module.

Comment: @ Thariama: i am glad to know it has helped you

Comment: @lamsuhail: it did not help me, but hopefully will help others who come across the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Under global configuration go to text filtering and set public to no filtering

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE (and most other Editor-Plugins) try to output/save the best possible HTML-code, thats why your HTML gets changed.

Go to "Site" => "Global Configuration" => "Text Filters" and set the appropriate filters. You might want to use a custom Blacklist by editing the 'Filter Tags'- & 'Filter Attributes'-fields. :)

*answer for Joomla pre-2.0:*
You can find the 'Clean code on save'-option in the settings (go to "Extensions" => "Plugins" => "Editor - TinyMCE" and go through the options on the right side).

Greetings

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but there is no such option called  'Clean code on save' in the Tiny Editor settings.

Comment: Ah sorry, looked in an old (1.6.0) Joomla-Installation :( Updated my answer above to really answer your question...

Comment: ok.In my current settings i have Filter Groups:Super Users-> No filtering selected..